# Debian PPTPD Misunderstanding

Tags: debian, vpn, pptp

I have just installed `pptpd` on a debian server, configured the ip to `10.0.0.1` and started the service. The service appears to be running on **eth0**: `gl.ob.al.ip:1723`, which is as expected.

However I thought that `pptpd` would create a new network interface, so that I could tell my `ftp` server to listen on `10.0.0.1`, but `ifconfig` only returns the **eth0** and **lo** interfaces. Have I misunderstood how this thing works? How should I configure services/daemons so that they are only available to the VPN clients?